# facebook graph api slow

Tags: facebook-graph-api, guzzle

The last few days calls to Facebook Graph Api v2.6 using GuzzleHttp have been far slower than normal. They now take around 15 seconds per request instead of around 2.

I do get the response I am expecting eventually and the same call with the same token in a browser does lead to the response within a couple of seconds.

I'm using an app token and there's nothing in the headers to indicate any sort of rate limiting, and there's nothing unusual on the api status pages.

Call:

```
graph.facebook.com/v2.6/search?type=page&q=Malmö&limit=40&access_token={token}
```

Edit: It also works fast on the Graph Explorer on FB's developer pages.

Comment: takes 1 second for me, in the api explorer.

Comment: It does for me too, it seems to be only GuzzleHttp that's slow.